# Mercurial and BitBucket, "abort: repository default-push not found!" error message

Tags: mercurial, bitbucket

I've some code on my laptop I would like to upload through Mercurial on my BitBucket repository.
I'm using a Linux CentOS 6 machine.

The problem is that if I type `$hg push`, I get the following error message:

```
pushing to default-push
abort: repository default-push not found!
```

What should I do?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Mercurial doesn't know where you want to push to. Mercurial first looks for the destination in the push command (which could be either a repo on the filesystem, or a remote hg server):

`hg push remoterepo`

If it doesn't find a destination in the command, it will fall back on the defaults.

Normally, assuming this repository was cloned, the hgrc file (in .hg/) will indicate the default repository to be used.

However this assumes that the repository was created by cloning an existing repo.

If not, you can edit .hg\hgrc and add the default destination eg:

```
[paths]
default-push=http://yourserver/
```